# .txt file extension in terminal

Tags: c, terminal

How come when I type in "(filename).txt" as part of one of the argument in terminal my code doesn't run and gives me a segmentation fault (core dumped)? but if I type "(filename)" instead then the code runs perfectly?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv){

FILE *inFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
FILE *outFile = fopen(argv[2], "w+");

char ch = fgetc(inFile);

while(ch != EOF){
     fputc(ch, outFile);
     ch = fgetc(inFile);
}

}
```

I skipped error checking writing this small sample code of what I mean. Terminal input would be

- "./(program name) (filename).txt (filename2).txt" but this produces a segmentation fault (core dumped)

Whereas, if I type this in

- "./(program name) (filename) (filename2) without the .txt file extension the code runs

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about what you're doing.  What is your code?  What exactly are you typing at the prompt?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  There is no way we can possibly help you with this since there simply isn't enough information to allow us to do anything.  Please read up on how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and provide us with one.  You need to show your code and the command lines that work and produce the crash.

Comment: we cannot guess as to your code.  Please post the code.  This seems to be a runtime problem, but without the actual (or minimal executable that still exhibits the problem) how could we ever help you?

Comment: You need to post your *actual* code. Copy-and-paste it from your source file into the question. The code currently in your question will not compile; you have a misplaced `"` on the 4th line, you're missing the required `#include <stdio.h>`, and you're comparing a `FILE*` to `EOF`.

Comment: Once you fix those problems: `fgetc` returns an `int`, and the result needs to be stored in an `int` so you can compare it to `EOF`.

Comment: Edited the code so it compiles and runs. If the argument input has .txt extension it gives me segmentation fault and when it doesn't have the .txt it runs perfectly

Answer (score 0):

If you put a debug statement as the first thing in your program printing the contents of argv[1] and argv[2] then *you* will be able to see the problem and we won't have to guess exactly what you are trying to do.  It is very hard for us to understand this issue with a MCVE because you are opening files that exist on your computer but which might not exist on ours.  So it could crash on your machine, but have some different error on mine.

"I skipped error checking" ... well that's fine when things work, but here something is going wrong: why not check the return codes and print out the error if there is one. For example:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main (int argc, char **argv){

    FILE *inFile; 
    FILE *outFile;

    if (argc < 3) {
       fprintf("Only got %d arguments!\n", argc);
       exit(1);
   }

    printf("arg1: %s, arg2: %s", argv[0], argv[1]); 

    inFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (inFile == NULL) {
          perror("Failed on in file: ");
          exit(1);
    }
    outFile = fopen(argv[2], "w+");
    if (outFile == NULL) {
          perror("Failed on out file: ");
          exit(1);
    }
    int ch = fgetc(inFile); /*as per comments this should be int */

    while(ch != EOF){
         fputc(ch, outFile);
         ch = fgetc(inFile);
    }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm still new to C so everything is a bit new to me. The error that pops up for me when I put in argument with .txt extentsion is "No such file or directory"

Comment: Well that is because `filename` exists but `filename.txt` doesn't exist, just as the error tells you.  That's why you need to check the return codes and print out an error.  In this case your program was okay but failed with `Segmentation Fault` any time the user used it incorrectly (e.g. calling `program_name file1` would also seg fault, but it isn't a programming mistake per se).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in your program should behave differently depending on the name of the input or output file.

But you don't check whether the `fopen()` calls succeeded.

I think what's happening is that the input file with the `.txt` extension simply doesn't exist. This causes `fopen` to fail, returning a null pointer, which you then assign to `inFile`. `fgetc(inFile)` then crashes.

Always check whether your calls succeeded or failed.

And as I mentioned in a comment, you need to assign the result of `fgetc()` to an `int`, not a `char`. It returns *either* a character value *or* the negative value `EOF`.

In addition you don't need two calls to `fgetc`, one before the loop and the other in the loop.

Suggested reading: section 12 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).